# Node.js MongoDB ObjectId to string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

IN Node.js, with MongoDB, Mongoosejs as orm

I am doing this

I have a model, User

```
User.findOne({username:'someusername'}).exec(function(err,user){
console.log(user) //this gives full object with something like {_id:234234dfdfg,username:'someusername'}
//but

console.log(user._id) //give undefined.
})
```

Why? And how to get the _id to string then?

Comment: Please note that the answers using .toString() will only work with mongoose, not any of the native mongodb drivers (as per 2.2, where you must use .toHexString()

Comment: .toString() worked for me using mongojs driver as well

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/

Answer (score 174):

Try this:

```
user._id.toString()
```

A **MongoDB ObjectId** is a 12-byte UUID can be used as a HEX string representation with 24 chars in length. You need to convert it to string to show it in `console` using `console.log`.

So, you have to do this:

```
console.log(user._id.toString());
```

Comment: Note though that this will only work using mongoose - this is not supported in mongodb.

Comment: @UpTheCreek, No, I used it with only MongoDB. I used it [here](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/NodeJS-Beginner-Projects/tree/master/people-information-db).

Comment: Since mongo 2.2 it does something else. See the docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/  I guess you must be using and older version of mongodb?

Comment: No, I use Mongo 2.4.4 and my project still works. Tested it one minute ago.

Comment: Can confirm that it does not work with my app using mongodb2.4 and mongoskin (which uses the mongo-native driver).  Check by typing (new ObjectId().toString()) in the mongo shell - you get a string, but it's not just the hex string.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32498/discussion-between-john--and-upthecreek)

Answer (score 30):

Take the underscore out and try again:

```
console.log(user.id)
```

Also, the value returned from id is already a string, as you can see [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/548#issuecomment-2245903).

Comment: I just want to note that this does not work for mongoose@4.6.8.

Comment: Ha I just posted the same thing below
@writofmandamus its working fine for me on 5.4.19

Answer (score 24):

I'm using mongojs, and I have this example:

```
db.users.findOne({'_id': db.ObjectId(user_id)  }, function(err, user) {
   if(err == null && user != null){
      user._id.toHexString(); // I convert the objectId Using toHexString function.
   }
})
```

Answer (score 19):

try this:

```
objectId.str;
```

see [doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/).

Comment: With a little bit more context this would be the perfect answer.

Comment: The linked doc here doesn't mention a `str` property of ObjectId-type objects.  It does, however, describe the `ObjectId.toString()` method, which as far as I can tell is the best answer.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using Mongoose, the only way to be sure to have the id as an hex String seems to be:

```
object._id ? object._id.toHexString():object.toHexString();
```

This is because object._id exists only if the object is populated, if not the object is an ObjectId

Answer (score 4):

When using mongoose .

A representation of the `_id` is usually in the form (received client side)

`{ _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: <Buffer 5a f1 8f 4b c7 17 0e 76 9a c0 97 aa> },`

As you can see there's a buffer in there. The easiest way to convert it is just doing `<obj>.toString()` or `String(<obj>._id)`

So for example

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect("http://localhost/test")
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String })
var Person = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema)
var guy = new Person({ name: "someguy" })
Person.find().then((people) =>{
  people.forEach(person => {
    console.log(typeof person._id) //outputs object
    typeof person._id == 'string'
      ? null
      : sale._id = String(sale._id)  // all _id s will be converted to strings
  })
}).catch(err=>{ console.log("errored") })
```

Comment: I don't think so. That was what return to me `[object Object]`

Answer (score 2):

```
function encodeToken(token){
    //token must be a string .
    token = typeof token == 'string' ? token : String(token)
}

User.findOne({name: 'elrrrrrrr'}, function(err, it) {
    encodeToken(it._id)
})
```

In mongoose , the objectId is an **object** (console.log(typeof it._id)).

Answer (score 2):

starting from Mongoose 5.4, you can convert ObjectId to String using SchemaType Getters.

see [What's New in Mongoose 5.4: Global SchemaType Configuration](http://thecodebarbarian.com/whats-new-in-mongoose-54-global-schematype-configuration.html#schematype-getters).

Answer (score 0):

The result returned by `find` is an array.

Try this instead:

```
console.log(user[0]["_id"]);
```

Comment: That would be true if `find` was used, but this is `findOne`.

Comment: This does indeed work with `find`. Spent two hours trying to find this information. Thank you.

Comment: OR console.log(user[0]._id);

Answer (score 0):

Access the property within the object id like that `user._id.$oid`.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple use `String(user._id.$oid)`

Answer (score 0):

try this : `console.log(user._doc._id)`

Answer (score 0):

None of the above was working for me. I had to use

```
import { ObjectID } from 'bson';

(id as unknown as ObjectID).toString('hex');
```

In typescript

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to achieve it ...

```
objectId.toString()
```

Using String Constructor

```
String(objectId)
```

Using Template Literals

```
const stringId = `${objectId}`;
```

Using Concatenation

```
const stringId = '' + objectId;
```

Using JSON.stringify

```
const stringId = JSON.stringify(objectId);
```