# Mongoose - no '_id' property in retrieved documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, mongoose

I have a website written with Meteor and external nodejs server that works with meteor's mongo. I create new documents in collection `tradeOffers` on Meteor side and poll for new documents in this collection on external server (I use mongoose). Everything works fine except that mongoose returns documents without the '_id' property.
My code is something like this:

```
// Meteor
var TradeOffers = new Mongo.Collection('tradeOffers');
TradeOffers.insert({ ... });

// Mongoose
var tradeOfferSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... }, { collection: 'tradeOffers' });
var TradeOffer = mongoose.model('TradeOffer', tradeOfferSchema);
TradeOffer.find({}).exec(function(err, results) {
  results.forEach(function(tradeOffer) {
    console.log(tradeOffer._id); // undefined
  });
});
```

I noticed that documents created in Meteor have '_id' field of type 'String' and documents created with mongoose have '_id' of type 'ObjectId'. But even if that's the problem, how do I solve it? I could not find any information. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You answered it yourself `_id` is an `ObjectId` wich can't be logged like this you would need to parse it to as a String `console.log(tradeOffer._id.toString());`. Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104690/nodejs-mongodb-object-id-to-string)

Comment: @DerTieran already tried that. It says `'Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined'.`

Comment: @DerTieran if you see from a `console.log`, the thing you're trying to log either has its `toString` to return `"undefined"` or it is the said string, or it is really is `undefined` (the most likely result).

Comment: @starky have you tried to log the whole Object so `console.log(tradeOffer)` so you can see if `_id` is defined?

Comment: Have you tried to `log` the whole object? How does your schema look like? Do you have one of the `_id` and `id` options set? Can you verify that the objects have an Id in the database (e.g. with the `mongo` client).

Comment: @DerTieran It's not defined.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. Yes, I did try log the whole object and there was no '_id' or 'id' properties. But using mongo client I can see there is '_id' field and it's a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by adding `_id: String,` to schema definition.