# Network Error with Axios on server with express.js

Tags: react-native, express, axios, localhost

I ran an API on localhost:3000 with express.js and here is the result:

```
0   
_id:    "610bcbd9c0ce881847bfd5b6"
__v:    0
1   
_id:    "610bcc43c0ce881847bfd5b8"
name:   "haaa"
title:  "data"
title2: "data2"
__v:    0
2   
_id:    "610bcc5ec0ce881847bfd5ba"
name:   "haaa"
title:  "data"
title2: "data7"
__v 0
3   
_id:    "610bcd00303b9a1b041d9d6a"
name:   "haaa"
title:  "data"
title2: "data7"
__v:    0
```

when I run axios.get I receive an error.

codes on app.js:

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
    useEffect(() => { 
        async function fetchmyapi() {
            try {
            let response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/')
            setData(response)
            console.log(data)

            }
            catch(error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
        fetchmyapi()
        }, [])
```

and here is the error in console.log :

```
Network Error
at node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:1:0 in <global>
at node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:74:24 in handleAbort
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:600:10 in setReadyState
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:395:6 in __didCompleteResponse
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

what is the problem, may i use something else rather than Axios?

Answer (score 2):

so finally i could figure it out:

1- don't use `localhost:3000` as Url, find your IP of network and use it instead like `192.168.1.102`

2- `Axios` makes problems. use `fetch` instead

```
useEffect(() => { 
        async function fetchmyapi() {
            try {
            let response = await fetch('http://yourIP:3000/')
.then((response) => response.json())
            setData(response)
            }
            catch(e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        }
        fetchmyapi()
        }, [])
```

Comment: Using the local IP address worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because `_id`
When you send data from backend to frontend, you need to convert _id from ObjectID to string.
If you are doing it, there aren't errors.

Comment: thanks for answer. can u give me more detail. what should i do?

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104690/nodejs-mongodb-object-id-to-string/34445430` Please check this.

Comment: What module do you use to connect with mongodb? `mongoose' or `mongodb`?

Comment: i use mongoose,

Comment: ` app.get('/',(req,res) =>{
    Ads.find({})
    .then(data =>{
        console.log(data)
        _id.toString()
        res.send(data)
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
  })
  }) `

Comment: `_id.toString()` did you tried to use it?

Comment: should i convert `_id` to string here? and how?

Comment: it tells me `_id is not defined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235678/discussion-between-arsiki-and-forest-1).